# General error: 1005 Can't create table ,Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

why laravel schema reply

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `test`.`#sql-13cc_d0` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `cities` add constrai
>     nt `cities_provinces_id_foreign` foreign key (`provinces_id`) references `provinces` (`id`) on delete cascade)
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create
>   table `test`.`#sql-13cc_d0` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed")

first table

```
Schema::create('provinces', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->boolean('is_enable');
        $table->boolean('is_deletable');
        $table->boolean('is_editable');
        $table->boolean('deleted');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

second table

```
    Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('province_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->boolean('is_enable');
        $table->boolean('is_deletable');
        $table->boolean('is_editable');
        $table->boolean('deleted');
        $table->timestamps();


        $table->foreign('province_id')
            ->references('id')->on('provinces')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make sure, your `provinces` table migration is running before `cities` table migration.

You should change `provinces` or `cities` migration file name to make sure timestamp at the beginning of `provinces` table migration file will be before `cities` table.

Answer (score 5):

The time go ahead but i will comment something else.

Andile is right! You must have the same type. In this case, the foreign key should have the type `bigInteger` because you have `bigIncrements` on the reference table.

I think thats the solution for a little and boring debug. (sorry for my english)

Comment: Actually, I knew this before. But I forgot. The referenced table for ForeignKeys always needs to be created first. I changed the timestamps of the tables. I already created the table I referenced. The answer worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create table first and then add constraint:

```
Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('province_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->boolean('is_enable');
    $table->boolean('is_deletable');
    $table->boolean('is_editable');
    $table->boolean('deleted');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('province_id')->references('id')->on('provinces')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key and referencing table must be same type, the auto generated id are of bigInteger, so instead of defining your column as Integer use bigInteger insteated. That Solved the problem for me